# Replacing ListFragment with another ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two almost identical ListFragment **A** & **B**, except that they draw data from their respective Asynctasker.

onListItemClick at **A** will result in Fragment **A** being replaced by **B**. However, my app always get stuck at the constructor of its CustomAdapter in **B**.

```
private class CustomAdapter_B extends ArrayAdapter<MatchType> {
            // Stuck Here
            CustomAdapter_B() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.color_match_type_s2, matches_type_s2);
            }
```

**Fragment A**

```
    public class Fragment A extends ListFragment implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener<ArrayList<MatchType>>{

        ArrayList<MatchType> matches_type = new ArrayList<MatchType>();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private static FirstPageFragmentListener main_caller;


        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                    //Interface, triggering Fragment Replace in my Fragment Adapter
            main_caller.onMySignalWithNum(1, (matches_type.get(position).getLink()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// AsyncTasker to draw data for ArrayAdapter
LoadMatchType lmt = new LoadMatchType(this);
            lmt.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTaskComplete(ArrayList<MatchType> result) {
            dialog.dismiss();       
            //result.remove(result.size()-1);
            matches_type = result;

            setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
            }
        }

        //Custom Adapter
        private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MatchType> {
            CustomAdapter() {
                super(getActivity(), R.layout.color_match_type, matches_type);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View row = convertView;

                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_match_type, parent, false);
                }

                TextView tv_type = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_type);
                tv_type.setText(matches_type.get(position).getType());

                TextView tv_tweet = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_tweet);
                tv_tweet.setText(matches_type.get(position).getTweet());

                TextView tv_tph = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_tph);
                tv_tph.setText(matches_type.get(position).getTph());

                return row;
            }   
        }

        public static Fragment newInstance(
                FirstPageFragmentListener pageFragmentListener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            footOddsFragment frag = new footOddsFragment();
            main_caller = pageFragmentListener;
            return frag;    
            }   
    }


    //INTERFACE
    interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener<T> {
           public void onTaskComplete(ArrayList<MatchType> result);
    }
```

Fragment **B** is about the same.

The app will get stuck at Fragment B's CustomAdapter constructor and the screen will be blank.

Oh, and everything works fine if I abandon Fragment *B* and just call the Asynctasker_B in onListItemClick in Fragment *A*. Just that I can't press back to view the previous list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget Fragment B.  Override your back press, put an `if` in there to determine if List B is active, if it is, change it back, otherwise perform the normal back function.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //  Code here to change list or go back.
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like a 'addToBackStack', or save the state of List A? Because I don't want to use AsyncTasker to load data into Fragment A everytime I press 'back' in List B.

I asked this question before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210872/getting-back-previous-data-from-listfragment-when-pressing-back-button)

Comment: I haven't played with it much (nor do I have anything close to experiment with), but I believe you can just change the adapter backing the list (point the listview to the new adapter), call `notifyDatasetChanged` to force a redraw of the list and go on.  This would leave the previous adapter in play (but not connected to anything).  Then just change them back.